# How can I set I checkbox to true in a MATLAB gui?

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I need a checkbox to be checked by default on creation of the gui. How can this be done in MATLAB? I looked through the uicontrol inspector without any luck.

Comment: +1 - Just because you found the answer doesn't make it a good question for others.

Comment: @Marc: I am not sure if you think it is a valid question or not. Since you write "+1" and then go on and say it is not a good question. I agree it is not a spectacular contribution but I just wasted have an hour looking for this option.So just in case somebody is as dense as I am, I am leaving the question up.

Comment: My phrasing was poor.  I do believe that it was a good question for others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also set it in the opening function (or on another callback) by inserting the following line:

```
set(handles.checkbox1,'Value',1);
```

or replace 'checkbox1' with whatever tag you have assigned to your checkbox. To uncheck, simply set the value to zero. This way, if you have two mutually exclusive options, when you select one you can automatically deselect the other:

Answer (score 2):

I found it. I leave this answer up. Just set "value" in the inspector to "1". It can be found at the very bottom of the uicontrol inspector.
Why is it that when I just asked a question, I find the answer myself?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the state of the checkbox on creation with 'Value' the property:

```
uicontrol(..., 'Value', 1);
```